# Vuforia raycast cant differentiate between 2 objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, raycasting

So I have 2 objects on my imageTarget and i added a box collider to both of them. I also added a different tag to them. I want it so that if you click on one of them it brings you to a different scene with info about that object. 
This is my code:

```
 using System.Collections;using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using Vuforia;
 using System.IO;


 public class ObjectInfo : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject Eagle;
     public GameObject LibertyStatue;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    Eagle = GameObject.Find ("Eagle");
    LibertyStatue= GameObject.Find ("LibertyStatue");

    //Eagle.SetActive (true);
    //LibertyStatue.SetActive (true);

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if(hit.collider.tag == "Eagle");
            {
                ChangeScene ("EagleInfoScene");
            }
            if(hit.collider.tag == "LibertyStatue");
            {

            ChangeScene ("LibertyStatueInfoScene");
            }
        }

    }
}
    public void ChangeScene (string a)
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (a);
    }
}
```

When i first added only one of the objects it worked fine, now after adding a new object and a new scene, both objects change to the new scene. So clicking both the eagle and liberty statue changes the scene to LibertyStatueInfoScene.  Is there a way to fix this?

**Solved:** Wow im really stupid, the issue was that i had semicolons after my if statements, it didn't give me an error so i never noticed it.

Comment: Add a `return;` after changing each scene

Comment: i solved it, i noticed i had semicolons after the if statements, removing them solved the issue .

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I didnt notice the semicolons after the if statements, removing them solves it. Strangely it didn't give me an error.